# Swift NSData from base64encoded string returns nil

Tags: swift, base64, nsdata

I'm communicating with a server in Swift retrieving image data. The incoming data is encoded as a base64 string. I am able to correctly receive and display the encoded strings. When I go to use the `NSData` class to decode the string back to binary data and display...

```
println(NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(0)))
```

The output is

```
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

One for each of the images received.

I've also tried

```
println(NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: nil))
```

and the same results. Is there anything I am missing along the way?? I would put the image strings up but they are massively long...

Comment: Could you share the base64 string for the image that you are working with? It would be a lot easier to tell you where the point of failure is that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use IgnoreUnknownCharacters option.

Or try to use initWithBase64EncodedString from [NSDataAdditions](https://github.com/myell0w/TBXML-Encoded/blob/master/NSDataAdditions.m)

Comment: IgnoreUnknownCharacters option did the trick! Thanks! Any tips as to what was wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have leading or trailing spaces or some invisible characters in your string.

Comment: Oh yes, in our application that is likely. That's gotta be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

For others that may be having this issue, make sure your Base64 encoded string has a length divisible by 4 (`=` should be used to pad the length).

See this StackOverflow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36366421/330494

Answer (score 5):

Based on Frank Schmitt's and Barlow Tucker's answers I've created an extension to `Data` to better handle base64 encoding:

```swift
extension Data {
    static func decodeUrlSafeBase64(_ value: String) throws -> Data {
        var stringtoDecode: String = value.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "+")
        stringtoDecode = stringtoDecode.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "/")
        switch (stringtoDecode.utf8.count % 4) {
            case 2:
                stringtoDecode += "=="
            case 3:
                stringtoDecode += "="
            default:
                break
        }
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: stringtoDecode, options: [.ignoreUnknownCharacters]) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "decodeUrlSafeBase64", code: 1,
                        userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Can't decode base64 string"])
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

so in your code, you can use it like this:

```swift
let baseEncodeText = "(.....)" //your base64 encoded string
let data = try Data.decodeUrlSafeBase64(baseEncodeText)
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I’m using this code in my app and it is working fine, so maybe your Base64 string is malformed, you can check it online i.e. https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Yes you are correct, or, actually, my base64 string had a header.payload.signature which fails when creating Data(…) So if I just extract the payload part then it works :-)

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen if the input is so-called "URL Safe" Base64 data. This data has the `+` symbol replaced by the `-` symbol, and the `/` symbol replaced by the `_` symbol.

Fortunately it's straightforward to convert it:

```
inputString = [[inputString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"+"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@"/"];
```

A [full list of variants is available on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table).